# Ошибка в консоли python

Tags: python

Делаю крестики нолики и консоль вывела ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ttt.py", line 75, in 
screen.fill(black)
NameError: name 'black' is not defined

Если что,то ошибка кода в самом конце

Код:

```
import sys

def check_win(mas,sign):
    zeroes = 0
    for row in mas:
        zeroes+= row.count(0)
        if row.count(sign)==3:
            return sign
    for col in range(3):
        if mas[0][col]==sign and mas[1][col]==sign and mas[2][col]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][0]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][2]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if zeroes==0:
        return 'Piece'
    return False


pygame.init()
size_block = 100
margin = 15
width = height = size_block*3 + margin*4

size_window = (width,height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size_window)
pygame.display.set_caption('Крестики нолики')

back = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
mas = [ [0]*3 for i in range(3)]
query = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            col = x_mouse // (size_block+margin)
            row = y_mouse // (size_block + margin)
            if mas[row][col] == 0:
                if query%2==0:
                    mas[row][col] = 'x'
                else:
                    mas[row][col] = 'o'
                query+=1

    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if mas[row][col]=='x':
                color = red
            elif mas [row][col]=='o':
                color = green
            else:
                color = white
            x = col*size_block + (col+1) *margin
            y = row * size_block + (row + 1) * margin
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,size_block,size_block))
            if color==red:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+5,y+5), (x+size_block-5,y+size_block-5), 3)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+size_block-5,y+5), (x+5,y+size_block-5), 3)
            elif color == green:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x+size_block//2,y+size_block//2),size_block//2-3,3)
    if (query-1) %2==0:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'x')
    else:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'o')

    if game_over:
        screen.fill(black)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('stxingkai', 80)
        text1 = font.render(game_over, True, white)
        text_rect = text1.get_rect()
        text_x = screen.get_windth() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        text_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        screen.blit(text1, [text_x, text_y])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Если что,то ошибка кода в самом конце

Comment: Ну у вас и в самом деле не существует никакой переменной black, больше здесь сказать нечего

Comment: Ошибка заключается в том, что name 'black' is not defined

Comment: Вы как-нибудь разнообразнее вопросы называйте, хоть чуть чуть сути в заголовок добавляйте, а то не отличить по заголовку - это новый вопрос или тот же самый

Comment: а вы из-за каждого чиха теперь будете вопрос задавать? или случится страшное, и вы попытаетесь сами разобраться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
back = (0, 0, 0)
```

Правильно так:

```
black = (0, 0, 0)
```

И всё же да - старайтесь сначала разобраться немного сами. Если вы писали код, вы же должны знать, зачем у вас переменная `black` и знаете, где она должна была быть объявлена. А там и до обнаружения ошибки недалеко.

Comment: аахаха, ясно, это я дурачек значит, благодарю